# MySQL trying to restore two foreign keys returns errors

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have this scenario: I have those two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_A (
  ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  product varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE sample_B (
  ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ref_id_sample_A_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NULL,
  ref_id_sample_A_ref_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NULL,
  document_name varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and I was trying to restore a foreign key between `ref_id_sample_A_id` of table `sample_B` and `ID` of table `sample_A` but executing this instruction:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_B
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_sample_B_ref_sample_A_id
    FOREIGN KEY (ref_id_sample_A_id) 
    REFERENCES sample_A(ID);
```

I obtain this error:

```
#1823 - Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'k3/fk_sample_B_ref_sample_A_id' to system tables
```

but I have no other foreign keys settled, neither informations if I query this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'sample_B';
```

I get empty result, and table `simple_A` is not a system table.... what I should do? Thanks in advance to all!

Cheers

Comment: Run `SELECT
 ID ,ref_id_sample_A_ref_id 
FROM sample_B 
WHERE ref_id_sample_A_ref_id  NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM sample_A )  and see if there are id that are not in the sample_A and this will cause problems

Comment: hello @nbk , I already tried that and it returned an empty dataset so between those two tables it should be OK about values between them.... about possible incongruent values was the first thing I thought at....

Comment: i am astraneged about your error message because with the sample and  a KEX you don't get an error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3a66e1c0b27da393bdbe1acb4fd6f37   check th emyql error log for erroro  like you have not enough space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved right 2 sec ago anyway ... had to export dump data of the table, drop the table and recreate the table with all constraints in CREATE TABLE instruction then re-import all dump data and it worked. Thanks anyway to everyone @nbk and @Bill Karwin! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your sample using MySQL 8.0.26, and got this error:

> ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_sample_B_ref_sample_A_id' in the referenced table 'sample_A'

This means the referenced column, `sample_A.ID`, is not valid as the referenced column of a foreign key, because it is not part of a key in that table.

The referenced column must be part of a key, and ideally should be a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY.

You did not define ID or any other column as the PRIMARY KEY for the table `sample_A`.

Comment: HI @Bill Karwin , looking with phpMyAdmin at the ID column of sample_A I see in Indices section for column ID:  `PRIMARY BTREE Yes No ID 128 A No ` so it's set as PRIMARY KEY...

Comment: Then you added the primary key but did not show it in the CREATE TABLE you posted in the question above.